# Qt - How to efficiently add a huge range of cells in a QTableWidget?

Tags: performance, gridview, qt5, cell

I'm completely newbie with Qt, and I need to add a huge range of cells in a QTableWidget. Each cell contains a custom widget, composed by an image and a text.

I use the following code to add the cells:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GridView::GridView(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_UI.setupUi(this);

    m_CellCount = 1000000;

    // add a new line if required
    m_UI.twGridView->setRowCount((m_CellCount / 7) + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_CellCount; ++i)
        AddGridItem(i);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void GridView::AddGridItem(int index)
{
    const int row    = (index / 7);
    const int column = (index % 7);

    QString                 text;
    QFont                   font("Segoe UI", 14);
    QFontMetrics            metrics(font);
    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> pImage(new QLabel());

    switch (index % 3)
    {
        case 0:
            text = metrics.elidedText("This is a very very long device name", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/Device.png) center center;");
            break;

        case 1:
            text = metrics.elidedText("iPod Shuffle Robbie", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/Shuffle.png) center center;");
            break;

        case 2:
            text = metrics.elidedText("iPad Robbie", Qt::ElideRight, m_UI.twGridView->columnWidth(column) - 10);
            pImage->setStyleSheet("image: url(resources/images/iPad.png) center center;");
            break;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<QLabel> pLabel(new QLabel(text));
    pLabel->setFixedHeight(20);
    pLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBottom);
    pLabel->setFont(font);
    pLabel->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(243, 243, 243);");

    std::unique_ptr<QWidget>     pWidget(new QWidget());
    std::unique_ptr<QVBoxLayout> pLayout(new QVBoxLayout(pWidget.get()));
    pLayout->addSpacing(10);
    pLayout->addWidget(pImage.get());
    pLayout->addSpacing(10);
    pLayout->addWidget(pLabel.get());
    pWidget->setLayout(pLayout.get());
    pWidget->setStyleSheet("background: none;");
    pImage.release();
    pLabel.release();
    pLayout.release();

    m_UI.twGridView->setCellWidget(row, column, pWidget.get());
    pWidget.release();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My issue is that the above code is acceptable for a small amount of cells, but adding a huge amount ruins the performances, in a not acceptable way (i.e until several dozen of minutes to open the view). By "huge amount", I'm speaking e.g about 1'000'000 cells.

What is the correct approach to add a such amount of cells in my grid view without ruin dramatically the performances, while respecting their content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a good performance, you should consider using a [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) with your own model.

A good start is [this tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I noticed that the most consuming code is those which creates the cell content. Unfortunately there is no way to make up for that, the only solution would be to create my own model. For that, the link you provided will help me, so I accept your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix you can try is disable GUI updates on the `QTableWidget` while adding items, and then re-enable them. Do this with `setUpdatesEnabled` method.

The best solution is to switch to using `QTableView`. You can first try with `QStandardItemModel` and if it isn't fast enough or uses too much memory, then create a custom model. But I have to warn, since you say you are a Qt newbie, Qt models and model views are among the most complex parts of the framework, so be prepared to do some studying (and indeed create working code with `QStandardItemModel` first as baseline).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed it seems that the best way to reach my objective is to create my own grid view model.